# SSIS - How to modify Event Handler

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis

Using VS2013, Built an SSIS package that works.  Added a custom error logging task to fire on error in the event handler tab.  I executed the package and got an error in the event handler execution so I opened the evnet handler tab so I could fix it, and the tasks are all gone.  I see there is now a drop down called Executables and I can see my custom logger in there.

How do I make the tasks visible so I can modify?

Comment: Ok, I see my task in the package explorer list under Event Handler > On Error > Executables. How do I open it for editing?

Comment: Wasn't working at first, then you said to do it, now it works. Thanks :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every object at the control flow has the ability to have an Event Handler. Based on what is or isn't selected will influence the scope of Event Handler that is defaulted to. You might have created the OnError event handler on your Task or it might be on the package itself. Easiest way to determine is to use the Package Explorer and find it.

Expand the Executables and double click the task

[image]